# jquery and php,the data send from my jquery code is not posted on php

Tags: jquery-ui

Below is my jquery code. It selects the corresponding tabs and according to that. It sends the html data

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $tabs = $(".tabs").tabs();
   $tabs.bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
      if(ui.index==0)
      {
         var data=$('div.display').html();
         $.post("echo.php", {index:data},function success(dat){
            // returnedData
            alert(dat);
         });
      }
      else if(ui.index==1)
      {
         var data=$('div.map').html();
         alert(data); 
      }
      else if(ui.index==2)
      {
         var data=$('div.system').html();
         alert(data); 
      }
      else if(ui.index==3)
      {
         var data=$('div.control').html();
         alert(data); 
      }
   });
});
```

My php (`echo.php`):

```
<?php

echo $_POST["index"];

?>
```

I'm posting the html code too:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="echo.php"><span><div class="display">DISPLAY DATA</div></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span><div class="map">MAP</div></span></a></li>
```

As brief i have to get the value display data in `$_POST["index"]`. Any other suggestions are welcome. Why is not working?

Comment: Have you tried some basic debugging? Set a breakpoint in Chrome or Firebug right at the call to `$.post()` and see if it gets hit; check your server log to verify that `echo.php` does in fact receive a request; log `$_POST['index']` to a file from within the echo script to see what's in there; call the echo script with curl or telnet to see what it actually spits out.

Comment: can u give a link to install firebug in linux,i have tried so much.

Comment: i'm a beginner in jquery and php,can u help to call the echoscript with curl or telnet.

Comment: Google "firebug". Go to firebug homepage. Find suitable version. Click install. Confirm. What's so hard about that?

Comment: curl and telnet have nothing to do with jquery or php, really, they are just general-purpose tools for driving network connections. Curl is a versatile downloader that speaks HTTP, FTP, and a few other protocols, and spits out the raw response body on stdout. Telnet goes a level deeper, allowing you to type the raw HTTP request yourself, including all headers - telnet itself doesn't implement HTTP, it just gives you direct access to the network socket. Both tools have man pages and online documentation, but they assume some knowledge of the HTTP protocol and general networking.

Answer (score 0):

Use browser console for debug client-side requests (firebug, dragonfly, etc) and do some debug actions on server e.g. file_put_contents('log.txt', serialize($_POST));

Comment: A `var_dump` or `var_export` is probably more useful than `serialize`, but in this case, it means `$_POST` is an empty array. Go find out why.

Comment: if $_POST - blank, then check correct request from javascript

Answer (score 0):

You callback in `$.post` should be an *anonymous* function. Try this:

```
$.post("echo.php", {index:data}, function(dat){
   // returnedData
   alert(dat);
});
```

Comment: Your version uses `function success(dat)`, it should be just `function(dat)`.

Comment: That's my point. You should pass an *anonymous* function, **no name**.